# Getting error in convert a string of a hex to a byte array in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to convert string that represents hex values into a byte array. This code is perfect working for even number string length but not for odd number string length. If string length is odd then I get java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Please help.

```
public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
     byte[] data = null;
         if(! s.equals("")){    
            int len = s.length();
            data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                     + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
            }
         }
     return data;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `String#getBytes()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop says to keep looping while `i < len` which allows i to be the string's last index within your loop, causing `s.charAt(i+1)` to access a non-existent byte.

Either change the loop condition to `i < len-1` or `i+1 < len`.

Answer (score 0):

data in case of odd number becomes of less size.

Suppose string length is 7 then data array would be of size 3,

7/2 = 3 (takes integer value)

Later in the loop you are trying to access data for 0 to 3 (which are 4 size).

Also you are accessing element in s.charAt(i+1) which is resulting larger index as your loop starts with 0 to 7. Value of i changes as :

0
2
4
6

when it is 6 then s.charAt(7) will throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. As string is of length 7 (index 0 to 6). 7th index is not present for string.

Solution is to reduce the no. of times loop is running by changing loop condition.